# Filter two strings in a listView

Tags: java, android

I have an sqLite database that contains a table that has 3 columns, I'm using in my layout an edittext and a ListView. What I've done by now is applying a search using the edittext and displaying the filtered results in a ListView.

The following code is applied to the edittext called myFilter, words is the simplecursoradapter :

```
myFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

       public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


       }

       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
         int count, int after) {


       }

       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
         int before, int count) {



        words.getFilter().filter(s.toString());

       }

   });
```

What I want to do is to filter two Charsequences, for example I want to display in my listView words that starts with a and b, can I do something like that (for example words.getFilter().filter("a","b"); ?

Comment: Please add the code for Simplecursoradapter#Filterable implementation part.

Comment: You can probably set filter or override getFilter for words. For words in turn you can redefine filter method.